# Nil instance variables in Rails view after subclassing Devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

To begin with, my goal was simple. I wanted to subclass Devise's `RegistrationsController` in order to override some of it's functionality, specifically the `new` method. Following along with the seemingly straightforward documentation from the Devise team, I built a custom controller that looks like this:

```
class Members::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def new
        super
        puts 'I am being called!'
        @var = 'This is a sentence going into a variable.'
        puts "@var is: #{ @var }"
    end
end
```

Now this file's path is `PROJECT/app/controllers/members/registrations_controller.rb`
Everything is output as expected... and we seem to be good here.

Moving on over to my view, where the problem is most evident, I find that `@var` is always `nil`. That has me pretty frustrated.

```
<h2>This is a custom sign up view.</h2>
<p>
    <%= @var %>
</p>
<p>
    Is @var nil?... <%= @var == nil %>
</p>

...Devise form stuff
```

So not only is `@var` not rendered in the HTML, but `@var == nil` is rendered as **true**.
This file's path is `PROJECT/app/views/members/registrations/new.html.erb`. Seeing that I achieve custom output, I'm led to believe that this file is also in a decent working order.

Lastly, I figured I might throw some of my `routes.rb` file into the mix, in case it should shed any light on the issue.

```
PROJECT::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :members, :controllers => { :registrations => "members/registrations" }
  devise_for :affiliates
  devise_for :admins

  root 'home#index'

  ...more routing stuff

end
```

I'm no expert, but this seems to be pretty easy stuff, yet I'm lost. In a floundering effort to fix my problem, I've done everything from use a different variable name (in case I was unaware of some `var` reserved word jankiness), to restart my Rails server (my ultimate last resort).  Any thoughts or advice would be **greatly** appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matching action in Devise parent controller has full rendering mechanism.

So, when you call `super`, the parent action took it over, work, and end the story. Your custom instance variable never had a chance to be copied to view.

To define custom things, do it before `super` or fully override the parent action.